# How to skip blank line of text while using fgets to print text (C)

Tags: c, file, pointers, fgets

dnd.csv file

[image: dnd.csv file]

I am a beginner to C, and I'm attempting to read a file (attached) with fgets.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("dnd.csv", "r");
    char *var;
    char varchar[301];
    var = &varchar[0];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    
    while (1)
    {
        fgets(var, 100, f);
        if (feof(f))
        {
            break;
        }
        //printf("%s\n", var);
        i = 0;
        while (*(var + i) != ',')
        {
            if (varchar[0] != '\n')
            {
                printf("%c", *(var + i));
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        printf(" is character %d\n", j);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

When I read and print it, it reads:

is character 0

Will is character 1

Mike is character 2

Dustin is character 3

Lucas is character 4

I want it to print without the first line so Will can be character 0 and Lucas 3.

I've been trying to figure out how to ignore the first line, but I haven't had any luck.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `*(var + i)` is more confusing than `var[i]`.

Comment: There's no need for the `var` variable, you can use `varchar` everywhere that you use `var`.

Comment: Why are you testing `if (varchar[0] != '\n')` instead of `if (*(var+i) != '\n')`?

Comment: No reason other than to test it out. I've trying to tweak things to see if I'm using a variable wrong anywhere

Answer (score 0):

If the character is empty, `i` will be `1` when the `while` loop ends. So check for that before printing "is character".

```
if (i != 0) {
    printf(" is character %d\n", j);
}
```

A much simpler solution is to just skip over the header line by calling `fgets()` once before the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("dnd.csv", "r");
    char varchar[301];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    fget(var, 100, f); // Skip header line
    
    while (fgets(varchar, sizeof varchar, f))
    {
        //printf("%s\n", var);
        i = 0;
        while (varchar[i] && varchar[i] != ',' && varchar[i] != '\n')
        {
            printf("%c", varchar[i]);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        printf(" is character %d\n", j);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

I've also simplified the loop condition by testing the return value of `fgets()`. It will return `NULL` when it reaches EOF.

And in the loop over the characters in the line, it should stop when it reaches newline or the null terminator of the string, in case there's no `,` in the line.

Comment: I tried adding 'if (I != 0)' before the printf function, but it still prints the same way it did before. I understand the concept of what you explained though.

Comment: Maybe there are spaces in the row?

Comment: I added a picture of the .csv file in the original post if that will help.

Comment: Why don't you just skip the whole first line? Just call `fgets()` once before the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you saying remove the `while (1)` loop, then go right into `fgets(var, 100, f)` ?

Comment: No, I'm saying to add an extra call to `fgets()` before the loop. That will read the first line, which you don't want to process in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the first by ignoring the first read of fgets(var, 100, f);
with "condition variable".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("dnd.csv", "r");
    char *var;
    char varchar[301];
    var = &varchar[0];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    
    int skipStep = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        fgets(var, 100, f);
        if(skipStep)
        {
            skipStep = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if (feof(f))
        {
            break;
        }
        //printf("%s\n", var);
        i = 0;
        while (*(var + i) != ',')
        {
            if (varchar[0] != '\n')
            {
                printf("%c", *(var + i));
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        printf(" is character %d\n", j);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Then your output will be like this.

[image]

however you code is not very readable nor clean, as you have separate whiles to print the name and other to determine the commas, i would suggest something more simple like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ch ,cntPeople = 0;
    int skipFlag = 1, skipFirstLine = 1;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("dnd.csv", "r");
    while((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
    {
         if('\n' == ch) /* Skip the first line and help with skip other text*/
         {
            skipFlag = 0;
            if(skipFirstLine)
            {
                skipFirstLine = 0;
                continue;
            }
         }
      if(skipFlag)
      {
          continue;
     }
     if(',' == ch) /* slip text after the names*/
     {
        skipFlag = 1;
        printf(" is character %d", cntPeople++);
        continue;
     }
     putchar(ch);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

with the output.

[image]

Hope this is Helps.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful! Would you have any recommendations to how I would accomplish the same task but for the traits? (i.e. Strength is trait 0, Dexterity is trait 1, etc). I'm currently able to print it correctly, but it's pretty clunky since I'm manually counting how many characters of the string to print. The string is, ",Strength,Dexterity,Constitution,Intelligence,Wisdom,Charisma"